# quick css/html display problems

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm building a WordPress basic site and I'm having a bit of a weird display problem where no matter what i do,  when hitting "return" on the visual editor, or manually entering "`&nbsp;`" or "`<br/>`" in the html tab, isn't creating **any** space between content. If you look at this test page here that i made to show what i mean, theres this long runoff sentence.

The code that has this looks like this

```
this is sentence one<br>
this is sentence two <br/><br/>
this is sentence three &nbsp;
this is sentence four &nbsp;&nbsp;
```

which should appear like so

```
this is sentence one

this is sentence two


this is sentence three 


this is sentence four
```

but when seen on WP front end, it shows like a long sentence.

http://tightlineinternetmarketing.com/mike-dev/thp2/?page_id=1930

If i manually go in and enter a bunch of  `&nbsp;` it creates sort of like a big space between words, not sentences.

The website has a basic/simple cssReset that i always use. The main css is normal as well. Just to be thorough, I've checked the code in the W3C validator and aside from 3 errors the menu plugin has, the rest is 100%. To test, i disabled the menu by commenting out that php code and the W3C returns 100% green.

I also checked the CSS and it too is 100% good/green.

ive gone line by line and i don't see anything that would make this happen. Im sure im probably missing something. Maybe need a new pair of eyes on this.

Any suggestions?
thanks in advanced.

Edit*** PROBLEM SOLVED. I figured it out after a day and a half.... SOMEHOW i used the wrong function to print the content on the page. on Page.php, i was using "`the excerpt();`" as opposed to "`the_content();`". Problem solved.

Comment: Those fonts... good god. It appears as though the issue is not with your css but with the act of saving the sentence. There is no breaks displayed so they are being lost somewhere along the line

Comment: lol @ ALi, if i knew where the problem was TRUST me i would have pasted it lol. Like i said i dont like going through simple code but i validated it all and alls mostly green so no real errors on the code.

Comment: If you go to the same link now, ive hardcoded the same code above in the wordpresss.php page and as you can see, it shows as it should but when wordpress does it, it appears messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Try entering that into the HTML editor instead of the visual editor.  The visual editor will strip out html tags, such as <br />.

Answer (score 0):

`&nbsp;` means one empty space. It doesn't do effect of `ENTER` tab. And I don't see `<br/>` in your html, you probably forgot to save the html file.
[image]